# Laptop stuck in boot after messing with Nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, asus

Laptop: ASUS TUF fx504GD
Hardware: Nvidia Geforce GTX1050ti 2GB
Intel core I7 8750 H

I will try to explain what happened and what I did:

1. I changed my default Graphics driver to Nvidia 535 driver from software & updates (which I soon found out was a big mistake). The laptop restarted and was stuck on this screen:

[image]

2. I tried to uninstall Nvidia driver by going to recovery mode and using `sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia_` after which laptop booted up but no kind of network was working, touchpad was not working and USB ports only worked for mouse. After this:
3. I selected old kernel from grub (I have dual boot of bunt 22.04 and Windows 11). After selecting old kernel (5.19.50), it booted up fine and was working perfectly, so I deleted new, nonfunctional kernel (6.2.0) and did some reboots to make sure everything was working fine.
4. After that I tried to install drivers available for my hardware (including Nvidia drivers) by what I thought was correct way, using `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` and everything seemed fine. The new Nvidia driver was 353 (tested) and I even rebooted to make sure it booted fine and it did. After the second boot I get this error:

[image]

but flashing. (during one of the booting attempts it said `Starting Nvidia daemon`). After pressing Alt + F1 (I think) it boots up to login screen and lets me write my password, but after logging in keyboard and the USB ports do not work.

I now am booted with even older kernel (everything works fine). selected Nvidia driver is still 353.

What even happened? I've been using Ubuntu for less than a year, and this never happened to me before.